# How can I join strings from VecDeque in Rust?

Tags: rust

This is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

let mut x: VecDeque<String> = VecDeque::new();
x.push_back("bye".to_string());
x.push_front("hello".to_string());
x.join(" "); // doesn't compile!
```

I'm expecting `hello bye` as a result.

What is the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to convert the `VecDeque` `.into()` a `Vec`, though as [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.from) says:

> This never needs to re-allocate, but does need to do O(n) data movement if the circular buffer doesn’t happen to be at the beginning of the allocation.

so ymmv on the efficiency front.

Alternatively, add a dependency on [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/) which has a number of nice utilities including [a `join` method](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join) (and also for your case [a helper `join` function](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.join.html) so you don't even need to convert the collection to an iterator).

Comment: Can you post a full example with `itertools`?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f21c55f8802b540308200faef16c128

Comment: As an alternative to simplest option, `VecDeque::make_contiguous` can also be used to have a slice, then join can be used([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb703e3885e95dc20ab1bf199d7790f0)), the obvious difference is: no need to move `Vecdeque` in this case, ofc this also does some rearrangement but this function have already been called internally via `VecDeque::into::<Vec>`